# Does a WCF Worker with a reserved IP use a different outbound IP on Azure?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure

I've got a WCF Worker in Azure with a reserved IP.  I'm using it to run a webservice that hits a third party, and that third party uses an IP whitelist for security.  When I was developing the webservice on my computer, I gave the third party my computer's public IP and all was well.  Now that I've deployed the webservice to the Azure Worker, I've given the third party the reserved IP of that WCF worker, but I'm getting an access denied error.  The third party confirmed that they've whitelisted the IP, and they say that they haven't gotten any requests from that IP today.  Does Azure use a different outgoing IP address or something like that?  Would spinning up a full VM to host my webservice fix this issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue running a WebAPI project on an Azure website, ended up needing to spin up a VM, think only VM's can have static IP's for outbound stuff sadly.

Comment: Can you output in logs of WCF service real public address?(by calling http://ipinfo.io/ip for example) How do you configure Reserved IP for your Worker?

Answer (score 1):

The outgoing IP address will be the Reserved IP, and this behavior is the same for either PaaS cloud services or IaaS VMs.  You can validate this by using RDP to connect to your PaaS VM and opening IE and browsing to one of the 'what is my IP' type services.

If you see an IP address different than your reserved IP then it is likely you didn't configure the reserved IP correctly and it is not getting applied to your service.  You can see the IP address assigned to your service in the management portal dashboard.

Comment: I couldn't figure out if remoting into the Cloud Service Worker instance was an option, so I just spun up a full VM.  WhatIsMyIP.com shows the correct IP address, so I'm reaching back out to the third party vendor.